# Polygon from postal code boundary

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

When searching for a postal code in google maps, e.g.

https://www.google.gr/maps/search/104+31,+Greece

it renders the postal code boundary as a polygon on the map. Is it possible to get this boundary using the maps api?

I've used the geocode api, but it just returns the bounding box, I want to get the actual polygon:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=104+31,+Greece

Any clues?

Comment: No, it is not possible to get that data from the Google Maps Javascript API v3 (at present).

Comment: Feature request in the issue tracker: [Feature: Automatic polygon generation to specified geographic boundary (e.g. state, country)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35816953)